# Incorrect Transfer Function - Control Systems

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I want to find the transfer function for a system described by this non-linear state-space model:
\begin{equation}
        X(t) =  \begin{bmatrix}
                y(t)\\
                v(t)\\
                \varphi (t)\\
                \omega (t)\\
                T_d(t)
                \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \dot X(t) = 
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    \dot y\\
                    \dot v\\
                    \dot \varphi\\
                    \dot \omega\\
                    \dot T_d
                \end{bmatrix} = 
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    v\\
                    y\omega ^2 - g\\
                    \omega\\
                    \frac{T_d}{my^2} - \frac{g}{y} - \frac{2\dot y\omega}{y}\\
                    \frac{1}{\tau}(k_m u(t) - T_d(t))
                    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix} x(t)
\end{equation}
The operating point for equilibtium state is given by:

$(\varphi _0 = 0)$.
\begin{equation}
T_{d}0=mgy_0
\end{equation}

This is how I obtain the transfer function:
\begin{equation}
s\Delta X_{1}(s) = \Delta X_{2}(s)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s\Delta X_{2}(s) = \Delta X_{1}(s)\Delta X_{4}(s) - g) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 s\Delta X_{3}(s) = \Delta X_{4}   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s\Delta X_{4}(s) = \frac{\Delta X_{5}(s)}{m\Delta X_{1}^2} - g\frac{1}{\Delta X_{1}(s)} - \frac{2\Delta X_{1}(s)\Delta X_{4}(s)}{\Delta X_{1}(s)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s\Delta X_{5}=\frac{1}{\tau}(kmu(t) - \Delta X_{5}(s))    
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Delta Y(s) = \Delta X_{1}(s)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Delta X_{5}(s) = \frac{kmU(s)}{s\tau  + 1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{K_{m}}{T_{d}(1 + \tau s)}
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you elaborate what each variable represents, especially which variables are considered the inputs to the system?

Comment: Just compute the Jacobian of the system at the equilibrium point, and, from that, the transfer function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system has no equilibrium point, so a transfer function from a linearization might not represent the actual system behavior even when the system is arbitrarily close to your point of linearization.

Note that you divide by $y$, so we need $y\neq 0$. However, this means that $\dot{v}=0$ only if $y=g/\omega^2$. Since you divide by $\omega^2$, it follows that $\omega\neq 0$ is necessary. However, $\dot{\varphi}=0$ if and only if $\omega=0$, a contradiction. So there is no operating point that satisfies the requirement of an equilibrium, namely that $\dot{x}=0$.

Note that this argument assumes $g\neq 0$. I guess $g$ stands for gravity of earth, so this assumption should be justified. If this is not true and in fact $g=0$ then you have an equilbrium at $v=0,\omega=0,T_d=0,u=0,\varphi\in R$ and $y\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

However, the transfer function in this case is $G(s)=0$ (independently of the choice of $\varphi$ and $y$), so not very useful either.